# Abp Controller does not show up when using [RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)] on EntityAppService

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

My custom controller does not show up in swagger.
This is my controller:

```
public class ProductController : ShopController
    {
        private readonly IProductAppService _productAppService;
        public ProductController(IProductAppService productAppService)
        {
            _productAppService = productAppService;
        }


        [HttpPost("api/app/product")]
        public async Task<ProductDto> CreateEntityAsync(CreateProductDto createProductDto)
        {
            var productDto = await _productAppService.CreateAsync(createProductDto);
            return productDto;
        }
}
```

This is my service:

```
[RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)]
    [ExposeServices(typeof(IProductAppService), typeof(ProductAppService), typeof(CrudAppService<
        Product, //The Product entity
        ProductDto, //Used to show Products
        Guid, //Primary key of the Product entity
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto,//Used for paging/sorting
        CreateProductDto,
        UpdateProductDto>))]
    public class ProductAppService : CrudAppService<
        Product, //The Product entity
        ProductDto, //Used to show Products
        Guid, //Primary key of the Product entity
        PagedAndSortedResultRequestDto, //Used for paging/sorting
        CreateProductDto,
        UpdateProductDto>, //Used to create/update a Product
    IProductAppService //implement the IProductAppService
```

I removed  [RemoteService(IsEnabled = false)] from ProductAppService, it generates auto api controller for Product and still does not see my custom product controller.

Comment: Can you see the "XXXModule" class of your project "XXX.Web"? I suspect that there is information missing in the `DependsOn(...)` attribute... Also see example here: https://github.com/abpframework/abp-samples/blob/master/BookStore-Mvc-EfCore/src/Acme.BookStore.Web/BookStoreWebModule.cs